# PHP simple html DOM remove all attributes from an html tag

Tags: php, html, attributes, simple-html-dom

```
$html = file_get_html('page.php');

foreach($html->find('p') as $tag_name) 
    {
        $attr = substr($tag_name->outertext,2,strpos($tag_name->outertext, ">")-2);
        $tag_name->outertext = str_replace($attr, "", $tag_name->outertext);        
    }
echo $html->innertext;
```

Above is the code I wrote to take what's inside all `<p>` tags in my html page and remove them.

---

My html code is similar to this :

```
<p class="..." id = "..." style = "...">some text...</p>
<p class="..." id = "..." style = "...">some text...</p>
<p class="..." id = "..." style = "...">some text...</p>
  <font>
    <p class="..." id = "..." style = "...">some text ...</p>
    <p class="..." id = "..." style = "...">some text ...</p>
  </font>
<p class="..." id = "..." style = "...">some text...</p>
```

---

If I run the php code , result would be this :

```
<p>some text...</p>
<p>some text...</p>
<p>some text...</p>
  <font>
    <p class="..." id = "..." style = "...">some text ...</p>
    <p class="..." id = "..." style = "...">some text ...</p>
  </font>
<p>some text...</p>
```

It doesn't remove `<p>` tags attributes that are inside `<font>`.
If anyone can help me with this I'll be appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I use your code and example HTML, it *does* remove all the attributes from all the `<p>` tags, even the ones inside `<font>`, so I'm not sure why yours isn't working.

But it looks like [simplehtmldom has methods](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm) that specifically deal with attributes so you don't have to use string functions:

```
$html = file_get_html('page.php');


foreach($html->find('p') as $p) {
    foreach ($p->getAllAttributes() as $attr => $val) {
        $p->removeAttribute($attr);
    }    
}
echo $html->innertext;
```

Hopefully that will be more effective.

Comment: TNX 4 ur answer but it gives me an error : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ((For 2nd foreach))

Comment: @SAM I edited the answer to correct an error. Give it another try?