# Looking for a systematic method of efficiently abstracting inline styles

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I am a junior-mid level developer.

I recently started a new job and I am tasked to essentially scrape an entire CRM project that has a huge majority of its styling done inline.

Objective: Clean out the inline styling to a shared folder that contains the .css file.

Problem: 50-100 of files that contain components with inline styles.

Goal: Adopt a systematic method to efficiently abstract the inline styles. While bringing some structure to this project.

Thoughts on any good methods of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach something like this using an HTML parser, like [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Your algorithm might resemble something like this:

1. Parse existing HTML to [extract inline CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769258/is-it-possible-to-extract-inline-css-from-html)
2. Write extracted styles to external CSS file
3. Make a second pass at your existing HTML to [remove the unwanted style attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794173/php-simple-html-dom-remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag)
4. Add `<link>` element in the HTML pointing to your new external stylesheet